# How to I transfer my VS 17 license to VS 19 that I downloaded?

Tags: visual-studio, license-key, product-key

I have VisualStudio 2017 Pro and 2019 Pro both installed.  2019 is complaining that my license will expire soon, but 2017 has never done that in years.
Can I provide my 2017 credentials to 2019 and continue using it?  How do I find my 2017 product key or whatever I need?